# IValueConverter is not working

Tags: wpf, binding, ivalueconverter

I want create a user permission validation to my system, I have created a `enum class Permission` contained all type of permissions, example: CanInsert, CanEdit, CanAccess, CanDelete, etc...

And in my `class User` has a property List contained all permission this user has

I created a `converter` `PermissionToVisibleHiddenConverter` for use in Visibility of controls

```
public class PermissionToVisibleHiddenConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        User loger = (User)value;

        /* Before edit
        if (loger.Permissao.Contains(Permission.Principal_AbrirLoja))
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        else
            return Visibility.Collapsed; */

        if (loger.Permissao.Contains(Permission.Principal_AbrirLoja))
            return Visibility.Visible;
        else
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

But it is not working when I try binding with this code

```
<!--<MenuItem Header="Abrir loja" Visibility="{Binding Loger, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibleHiddenConverter}, ElementName=window, TargetNullValue=Collapsed, Mode=OneWay}"/>-->
<MenuItem Header="Abrir loja" Visibility="{Binding Loger, Converter={StaticResource PermissionToVisibleHiddenConverter }, ElementName=window, TargetNullValue=Collapsed, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

Where window is this MenuItem parent similar this, but Loger is not null

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    User Loger { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

This code will not throw any exception or error, just do nothing

Where is problem?

Comment: In condition `loger.Permissao.Contains (Permission.Principal_AbrirLoja)` you in both cases the return `Visibility.Collapsed`. So conceived or is it a typo?

Comment: yes, I had put it for test, but my MenuItem is always Visible

Comment: In `MenuItem` you use `BoolToVisibleHiddenConverter`, but in question was indicated `PermissionToVisibleHiddenConverter`... possible for the test. Anyway, try set `Mode="TwoWay"` and remove `ElementName`, (you can also remove `TargetNullValue`) maybe help.

Comment: I tried it now, same thing, nothing error nothing effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Your property is not public 2) you need to notify

```
public partial class Window1 : Window,INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    User loger;

    public User Loger 
    { 
        get{return  loger;}
        set { loger= value; OnPropertyChanged("Loger "); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```